# Kyverno Policies on DockerHub (Private)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, policy

I was trying to apply Kyverno policies to an image in the private registry, but I come across this error.

```
Error from server: error when creating "deployment.yaml": admission webhook "mutate.kyverno.svc-fail" denied the request:

policy Pod/default/nginx for resource error:

verify-image:
  verify-image: 'failed to update digest: failed to fetch image reference: docker.io/*****/nginx:latest,
    error: GET https://index.docker.io/v2/*******/nginx/manifests/latest: UNAUTHORIZED:
    authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:*****/nginx Type:repository]]'
```

When the registry is set to public, the policies work without any issues. However, I require a private registry for my particular use case, and I have not yet found a complete solution for implementing the policies in this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried to run through this documentation: https://kyverno.io/docs/writing-policies/verify-images/#using-private-registries. ?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the Kyverno documentation you mentioned regarding verifying images. To establish trust for your private registry, there are two potential ways, as mentioned in documentation. The process comes at the cost of losing trust for any public registries such as Docker Hub, Amazon ECR, GitHub Container Registry, etc. So I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: it seems to me that it could be a good idea to reach out to Kyverno's github if you don't find any solution here.